# Jquery git version

Tags: javascript, jquery, git

I'm using jquery git version (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js) in my javascript and today when I opened the page, nothing works. It has worked for the last 3 years. Anyone else gets this? It looks like there has been updated at 2019-04-29T20:56Z. I know it unstable version, but is it I or anyone else also has this? When I use the 3.4 version, everything works fine. I'm using firefox and first error in console says `TypeError: $.isArray is not a function[Learn More]` and second

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).dialog is not a function @file:///C:/xxxx/xxx/xxx.js:20:19
mightThrow@http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js:3530:21
resolve/</process<@http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js:3598:12
 undefined
```

Comment: [Don't ever use `jquery-git` in production](https://jquery.com/download/#jquery-pre-release-builds): "The jQuery team is constantly working to improve the code. Each commit to the Github repo generates a work-in-progress version of the code that we update on the jQuery CDN. _These versions are sometimes unstable and never suitable for production sites._ We recommend they be used to determine whether a bug has already been fixed when reporting bugs against released versions, or to see if new bugs have been introduced."

Answer (score 1):

Git version currently links to 4.0 pre, which is a large overhaul of jQuery to reflect updates to JavaScript. `$.isArray` was thus deprecated in 3.2, and consequently removed in 4.0, because JavaScript now has `Array.isArray`.

`$.fn.dialog` was never a part of jQuery that I know of (you might be thinking of jQuery UI?)

Comment: Interesting, but why then 3.4 version works for me and why it broke down today? And your right, I meant jQuery UI.

Comment: Since you don't provide any code relating to jQuery UI, nor the link you are getting it from, I cannot comment on that part of the question at all. As for `isArray`, why wouldn't it work at 3.4? It was deprecated, but not yet removed. The date you cite is the date placed inside the code, which is presumably the date it was compiled for distribution, or possibly the date the commit was made; the server does not return a `Last-Modified` header so it is difficult to know when exactly the URL content was changed.

Comment: @pinq-,  it broke when the code was updated. Don't ever rely on unstable builds in production, especially ones that aren't pinned to even a major version release.